# submitting a form have random text

Tags: javascript

So I have everything working how it needs to be. textbox, radio and select all display correctly. along with the error for not putting anything in. I need to display a random text after the stuff are submitted. I've tried different things just no luck. I tried an array but I did something wrong with it. This is a .php extension. Any ideas

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ex 2</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
function checkForm(){

    var chk = true;
    var mName = document.getElementById("txtM");
    var meth = document.getElementById("methM");
    var rad = document.getElementById("radM");
    var sel = document.getElementById("selM");
    var heal = document.getElementById("a");
    var dark = document.getElementById("b");
    var ele = document.getElementById("c");
    var wep = document.getElementById("imp");       

        meth.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
        rad.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:none");


    if (mName.value=='no'){     
        document.getElementById("methM").innerHTML = "No";
        meth.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (mName.value=='yes'){        
        document.getElementById("methM").innerHTML = "Yes";
        meth.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (mName.value==''){
        document.getElementById("methM").innerHTML = "So You Don't Like To Do Any Damage?";
        meth.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (heal.checked) {
    document.getElementById("radM").innerHTML = "Healer";
    rad.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
    chk = false;
    }
    if (dark.checked) {
    document.getElementById("radM").innerHTML = "Dark";
    rad.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
    chk = false;
    }
    if (ele.checked) {
    document.getElementById("radM").innerHTML = "One with the Elements";
    rad.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
    chk = false;
    }   
    if (wep.value==1){
        document.getElementById("selM").innerHTML = "Rifle";
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (wep.value==2){
        document.getElementById("selM").innerHTML = "Bow and Arrow";
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (wep.value==3){
        document.getElementById("selM").innerHTML = "Daggers";
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (wep.value==0){
        document.getElementById("selM").innerHTML = "Gotta Have A Weapon!";
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="page">   
<main role="main">
<article>
    <div id="errMess" class="errMess"></div>
      <h1>What Guild Wars 2 Profession Are You</h1>

        <div class="cssTable" style="margin-top:-25px;">
        <form method="post">
          <table>
          <tr><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td><div align="right">Do you like to do high damage?</div></td><td width="217">
            <input id="txtM" name="txtM" type="text" size="25"></td><td ><div id="methM" style="display:none"></div></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="right">What best describes you?</div></td><td>
                <input id="a" type="radio" name = "group1" value="A">Healer</input>
                <input id="b" type="radio" name = "group1" value="B">Dark</input>
                <input id="c" type="radio" name = "group1" value="C">Earthling</input>               
                </td><td><div id="radM" style="display:none"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>What weapon would you like to have?</td>
                <td>
                <select id="imp"><option value="0" selected="true">Select One</option>
                <option value="1">Rifle</option>
                <option value="2">Bow and Arrow</option>
                <option value="3">Daggers</option></select>
                </td><td><div id="selM" style="display:none"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="3" align="right"><input type="button" class="styled-button-7" value="Send" onclick="checkForm()"/></td></tr></table></form></div></article>
                </main></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand... When you submit a form, the page will be reloaded. So your js script will listen for the form's submit event again. You need to generate this message in PHP or, if you want to use JS you need AJAX

Comment: i have it once it submits it counts everything as errors

Comment: this is php not html if thats what you are meaning

Comment: Does PHP receive and process the form data? After the PHP data processing you should redirect to the same page and add your message under the form. You could pass a get parameter as flag during the redirection and hence you can print your notification in html or with a js code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to show that text?

You can try with:

alert('random text');

or maybe:

document.getElementById("errMess").append("**Your info has been submitted**");

Comment: i guess under the form. not an alert though. its gotta be random everytime. like "you are a warrior" then "you are a ranger" ect.

Comment: `var randomtext= ["you are a warrior", "you are a ranger", "whatever"];
document.getElementsByTagName("form").innerHTML = randomtext[Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))];`